# With VSC Live Sass Compiler, is there a way to create multiple source directories which output to respective CSS directories?

Tags: css, sass, live-sass-compiler

I'm using VS Code and Live Sass Compiler to handle my SCSS files. We have our standard styles for various pages. Those files are sourced at `~/scss` and compile to `~/dist/css/`.

However, I'm starting to write out custom components and I want to link those component SCSS files differently. Those will be sourced at `~/scss/components` and compile to `~/dist/css/components`.

Is there a way, with Live Sass Compiler settings to create two source directories, and based on my source directory -- compile to a respective output directory?

```
  "liveSassCompile.settings.formats": [
    {
      "format": "expanded",
      "extensionName": ".css",
      "savePath": "/dist/css/"
    }
  ]
```

If there is another Sass compiler that can do this, please let me know. This is for a very large site and I need to get it right the first time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ritwick Dey's original Live Sass Compiler is no longer maintained (last update 11.07.2018), so I've moved to Glenn Marks' forked version here: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=glenn2223.live-sass

With that version, using a savePath like this should do what you want.

```
"savePath": "~/../dist/css/"
```

Check out the [Settings & Commands Docs](https://github.com/glenn2223/vscode-live-sass-compiler/blob/master/docs/settings.md) for more info.

Comment: That's interesting. I just saw the exact same advice yesterday in a YouTube video from Kevin Powell.